# converting pd.dataFrame to json and save it

Tags: python, json, pandas

I got a pandas dataFrame with 2 columns that looks like that:

```
data = [[30222, 5], [10211, 2], [30333, 3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'weight'])
```

and I wish to have it as a json file of the following form:

```
[
{"id":30222,"weight":5},
{"id":10211,"weight":2},
{"id":30333,"weight":3}
]
```

later, I would like to store it in HDFS (so I create a folder with the json file in it, which I will later upload).

what I tried to do is:

```
my_dict = my_df.set_index('id')['weight'].to_dict()

with TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
    temp_local_path = os.path.join(tempdir, "my_json")
    if boosting_nha_properties_dict is not None:
        with open(os.path.join(temp_local_path, "my_json.json"), "w") as f:
            json.dump(my_dict, f)
```

but it doesn't look the same format as I need the json, and also, it throws an exception:

"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmp36sdlarw/my_json/my_json.json'"

Thanks!

Comment: The FileNotFoundError is probably because you haven't created the 'my_json' directory in the temp directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to make a dictionary - you can export directly using [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html). You need to make the "my_json" directory first.

```
with TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
    temp_local_path = os.path.join(tempdir, "my_json")
    os.mkdir(temp_local_path)
    if boosting_nha_properties_dict is not None:
        df.to_json(os.path.join(temp_local_path, "my_json.json"), orient="records")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just try

```
d = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')
Out[210]: 
[{'id': 30222, 'weight': 5},
 {'id': 10211, 'weight': 2},
 {'id': 30333, 'weight': 3}]
```